# Java List with Object from different classes

Tags: java, eclipse, list, arraylist

I have the following question, I have a project with an upperclass Animal and
different subclasses (dog, cat, mouse ...). Now I want to create a list in another class in which objects from mouse, objects from cat ... are saved.
How exactly does that work, or what connection must this class have to the others?
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the list as being of the *greatest common denominator* of the classes it contains. So if you have:

[image]

...then it would be a `List<Animal>` because it can't be `List<Mouse>` (it'll have `Cat`s in it) and it can't be `List<Cat>` (it'll have `Mouse`s in it).

But if you had:

[image]

...it would be `List<Object>` because `Mouse` and `Cat` have no common class other than `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if these classes extend Animal, you can do

```
List<Animal> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

You should take a look at the concept of [inheritance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

If Animal is the superclass, you can create a list of type Animal. However, you will not be able to convert its items to the subclasses (mouse, cat, etc) without first checking their type. This isn't great practice, but it's doable.

```java
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
animals.add( new Mouse() );
animals.add( new Cat() );
animals.add( new Dog() );

for ( Animal a : animals ) {
    if ( a instanceof Mouse ) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```